# syntax error in sql update statement in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have this sql statement to update a column in access db from vb but when I run the program it shows that there is a syntax error in the statement. The code:

```
cmd.Connection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = 
    "UPDATE users SET password='" & 
    Me.pd.Text.Trim & "' WHERE password='" & Me.pd.Tag.ToString & "'"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`
```

The error shows that there is a syntax error in update statement. I've tried to find the error but in vain.

Comment: make sure that the password does not contain single or double quotes.

Comment: agreed, you should be using a parameterized query.  You're also  atttempting to update all rows that have the same password.  Is this intentional?

Comment: It contains non of those

Comment: Thanks @Phil. What I would like to know is why I get the syntax error? Is that statement syntactically incorrect?

Comment: It looks ok from my t-sql point of view.  I can't say for Access.  What does the generated CommandText look like?  If you set commandText = "UPDATE users SET password='foo' WHERE password='bar'", does that work?  What's syntax error is reported?

Comment: Your logic seems flawed - what if multiple users happen to have the same "strong" password like `password`? Then you'd be updating all of them. There should be a condition based on the user's **name** or login-ID or something, to update just that single user...

Comment: It's **wrong** to trim whitespace from passwords, it's **wrong** to store passwords as text in the database (you should store a hash) and it's **wrong** to build a query using string concatenation to substitute user data, and it's **wrong** to update all passwords of a type when one changes.

Comment: Agree with the statements re: need to target one user, also using parameters and inspecting the actual text you've constructed. So I'll pick a different criticism - you shouldn't (generally) be storing passwords - you should be storing salted hashes. (The exception to avoiding storing passwords is if you are storing passwords which are to be used against a *different* system which only offers password based authentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should do the update by a different field (e.g. user id, name, email) and not by the current password.

Try to use named parameters instead of string concatenation to avoid errors due to values containing `'` and SQL Injection.

You could also use `[name]` to escape the name of tables or fields (assuming you are using SQL Server).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx#Y684

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [users] SET [password]=@current_password WHERE [password]=@new_password"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current_password", Me.pd.Text.Trim)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_password", Me.pd.Tag.ToString)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you. You must right but then am using Access which I believe is abit different and again my main worry is why my statement is having an error

Comment: @ken access still supports query parameters

Comment: Thank you @mazzucci. I escaped the password field with `[]` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your question raised many other important issues as reflected in the comments you've received.  I don't want to dismiss any of those issues.  However I do want to draw your attention to the fact that `password` is a reserved word.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).

If you follow mazzucci's advice to bracket the table and field names, your syntax error could go away.  However you shouldn't actually need to bracket the table name because `users` is not a reserved word.